# heroku not loading language file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, byte-order-mark

Heroku does not seem to be loading `config/locales/pt.yml`. (Language is being set correctly to `pt`.)

I18n is working perfectly on localhost, but not on [my heroku server](http://deficit-puzzle.heroku.com/).
Code is at https://github.com/aneves/deficit-puzzle

localhost:

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.5)
irb(main):001:0> I18n.t(:Edit)
=> "Editar"
```

heroku:

```
$ heroku console
Ruby console for deficit-puzzle.heroku.com
>> I18n.t(:Edit)
=> "translation missing: pt.Edit"
```

#### possible dups:

There are SO matches for my problem, but those are dead threads. I do not want to open a bounty on a thread whose OP left comments unanswered, I'd rather have a good question with good follow up. Also, the questions do not pinpoint the problem accurately and, so, the answers miss the point.

1. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591896/heroku-language-locale-not-working-i18nmissingtranslationdata) has no answer and OP did not follow up on comments;
2. [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385172/heroku-language-locale-not-working) has only an answer that misses the point, and OP does not follow up on the last comment either.

Comment: Curiously, all translations are appearing in `I18n.backend` but not in I18n.t

Comment: @AlexanderWenzowski, THANKS! Your comment definitely counts as `An explanation to the problem, a way to fix the problem even without understanding it, or even hints strongly inducive to such a fix.`, in my book. But bounty cannot be assigned to comments. ;) Could you post the comment as an answer? (This I18n problem had been bothering me since the end of August 28th... meh)

Comment: glad to have been able to help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curiously, data were appearing in `I18n.backend` as expected but were not individually selectable using `I18n.t`

This led to the realization that the load path must be configured correctly for Rails to find the translation files, but that it was not parsing them properly.

This [led to @ANeves discovering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868309/#answer-8017048) that a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) was disrupting Heroku's ability to parse the files which [resulted in the fix](https://github.com/aneves/deficit-puzzle/commit/eea704726cbad6c04b747ac88a08bf7cf0a14354#config/locales) of removing the offending BOM.

---

#### Wikipedia on BOM in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)

> The Unicode Standard [does permit the BOM in UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#cite_note-1), but [does not
> require or recommend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#cite_note-2) its use. Byte order [has no meaning in
> UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#cite_note-utf-8-bom-3) so in UTF-8 the BOM serves only to identify a text stream or
> file as UTF-8.
>
> Many Windows programs (including Windows Notepad) add BOMs
> to UTF-8 files by default.

If future readers are on [ruby-1.9](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9) consider reading about [common encoding problems](http://gnuu.org/2009/02/02/ruby-19-common-problems-pt-1-encoding/).

Comment: And I actually think this is a better answer than mine, too. Marking also as answer.

Answer (score 3):

[@Alexander Wenzowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902839/alexander-wenzowski) sent me on the right track.

It seems the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) was messing up Heroku's loading of localization files...
When I converted the files to not have BOM, using Notepad++, everything got fixed.

At first I was just trying to inspect this new thing for me, I18n.backend... and then I noticed what I had missed at first sight: that even though the data was there, it was all mangled.

```
>> I18n.backend
=> #<I18n::Backend::Simple:0x7f74643e2f08 @skip_syntax_deprecation=false, @translations={:"\357\273\277# Sample localization file for English. Add mor
e files in this directory for other locales. # See http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails%2Flocale for starting points.\nen"=>{:Dest
roy=>"Remove", :suspend=>"suspend", :confirm=>"Are you sure?", :Admin=>"Administration", :suspended=>"%{model} was successfully suspended.", :Back=>"B
ack", :updated=>"%{model} was successfully updated.", :html_title=>"DeficitPuzzle", :to_frontpage=>"to frontpage", :approve=>"approve", :Show=>"Show",
 :to_admin=>"to administration", :theme=>{:n=>{:one=>"1 theme", :other=>"%{count} themes"}, :List=>"Listing themes", :New=>"New theme", :Destroy_perma
nently=>"Permanently remove this theme", :Editing=>"Editing theme", :_=>"Theme"}, :Progress=>"Progress", :Proposals=>"Proposals", :approved=>"%{model}
 was successfully approved.", :activerecord=>nil, :save_errors=>{:one=>"1 error prohibited this item from being saved", :other=>"%{count} errors prohi
bited this item from being saved"}, :proposal=>{:n=>{:one=>"1 proposal", :other=>"%{count} proposals"}, :List=>"Listing proposals", :New=>"New proposa
l", :Impact=>"Impact", :Destroy_permanently=>"Permanently remove this proposal.", :Editing=>"Editing proposal", :Approved=>"Approved", :"Approved?"=>"
Approved?", :_=>"Proposal", :Title=>"Title", :Description=>"Description"}, :helpers=>{:submit=>nil}, :created=>"%{model} was successfully created.", :
Edit=>"Edit", :title=>"Deficit puzzle: you fix the budget"}, :∩╗┐pt=>{:Destroy=>"Remover", :suspend=>"suspender", :confirm=>"De certeza?", :Admin=>"Ad
ministra├º├úo", :suspended=>"%{model} foi suspendida com sucesso.", :Back=>"Atr├ís", :updated=>"%{model} foi actualizada com sucesso.", :html_title=>"
DeficitPuzzle", :to_frontpage=>"ir para p├ígina principal", :approve=>"aprovar", :Show=>"Mostrar", :to_admin=>"ir para administra├º├úo", :theme=>{:n=>
{:one=>"1 tema", :other=>"%{count} temas"}, :List=>"Listando temas", :New=>"Novo tema", :Destroy_permanently=>"Remover este tema permanentemente.", :E
diting=>"Editando tema", :_=>"Tema"}, :Progress=>"Progress├úo", :Proposals=>"Propostas", :approved=>"%{model} foi aprovada com sucesso.", :activerecor
d=>{:attributes=>{:theme=>{:title=>"T├¡tulo"}, :proposal=>{:impact=>"Impacto", :description=>"Descri├º├úo", :title=>"T├¡tulo"}}, :models=>{:theme=>"Te
ma", :proposal=>"Proposta"}}, :save_errors=>{:one=>"1 erro impediu este item de ser salvo", :other=>"%{count} erros impediram este item de ser salvo"}
, :proposal=>{:n=>{:one=>"1 proposta", :other=>"%{count} propostas"}, :List=>"Listando propostas", :New=>"Nova proposta", :Impact=>"Impacto", :Destroy
_permanently=>"Remover permanentemente esta proposta.", :Editing=>"Editando proposta", :Approved=>"Aprovada", :"Approved?"=>"Aprovada?", :_=>"Proposta
", :Title=>"T├¡tulo", :Description=>"Descri├º├úo"}, :helpers=>{:submit=>{:update=>"Actualizar %{model}", :create=>"Criar %{model}"}}, :created=>"%{mod
el} foi criada com sucesso.", :Edit=>"Editar", :title=>"Deficit puzzle: tu consertas o or├ºamento"}, :en=>{:support=>{:array=>{:words_connector=>", ",
 :two_words_connector=>" and ", :last_word_connector=>", and "}}, :number=>{:precision=>{:format=>{:delimiter=>""}}, :format=>{:separator=>".", :delim
iter=>",", :precision=>3, :significant=>false, :strip_insignificant_zeros=>false}, :human=>{:storage_units=>{:units=>{:byte=>{:one=>"Byte", :other=>"B
ytes"}, :kb=>"KB", :mb=>"MB", :gb=>"GB", :tb=>"TB"}, :format=>"%n %u"}, :format=>{:delimiter=>"", :precision=>3, :significant=>true, :strip_insignific
ant_zeros=>true}, :decimal_units=>{:units=>{:million=>"Million", :unit=>"", :billion=>"Billion", :trillion=>"Trillion", :quadrillion=>"Quadrillion", :
thousand=>"Thousand"}, :format=>"%n %u"}}, :percentage=>{:format=>{:delimiter=>""}}, :currency=>{:format=>{:separator=>".", :unit=>"$", :delimiter=>",
", :precision=>2, :significant=>false, :strip_insignificant_zeros=>false, :format=>"%u%n"}}}, :datetime=>{:distance_in_words=>{:about_x_hours=>{:one=>
"about 1 hour", :other=>"about %{count} hours"}, :about_x_years=>{:one=>"about 1 year", :other=>"about %{count} years"}, :x_days=>{:one=>"1 day", :oth
er=>"%{count} days"}, :over_x_years=>{:one=>"over 1 year", :other=>"over %{count} years"}, :less_than_x_minutes=>{:one=>"less than a minute", :other=>
"less than %{count} minutes"}, :about_x_months=>{:one=>"about 1 month", :other=>"about %{count} months"}, :x_minutes=>{:one=>"1 minute", :other=>"%{co
unt} minutes"}, :almost_x_years=>{:one=>"almost 1 year", :other=>"almost %{count} years"}, :x_months=>{:one=>"1 month", :other=>"%{count} months"}, :l
ess_than_x_seconds=>{:one=>"less than 1 second", :other=>"less than %{count} seconds"}, :half_a_minute=>"half a minute", :x_seconds=>{:one=>"1 second"
, :other=>"%{count} seconds"}}, :prompts=>{:day=>"Day", :minute=>"Minute", :month=>"Month", :year=>"Year", :hour=>"Hour", :second=>"Seconds"}}, :time=
>{:formats=>{:default=>"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z", :short=>"%d %b %H:%M", :long=>"%B %d, %Y %H:%M"}, :pm=>"pm", :am=>"am"}, :date=>{:formats=>{:defaul
t=>"%Y-%m-%d", :short=>"%b %d", :long=>"%B %d, %Y"}, :abbr_day_names=>["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"], :order=>[:year, :month, :day]
, :day_names=>["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"], :abbr_month_names=>[nil, "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Ma
y", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"], :month_names=>[nil, "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "S
eptember", "October", "November", "December"]}, :errors=>{:format=>"%{attribute} %{message}", :messages=>{:even=>"must be even", :confirmation=>"doesn
't match confirmation", :greater_than_or_equal_to=>"must be greater than or equal to %{count}", :accepted=>"must be accepted", :equal_to=>"must be equ
al to %{count}", :not_an_integer=>"must be an integer", :empty=>"can't be empty", :wrong_length=>"is the wrong length (should be %{count} characters)"
, :less_than=>"must be less than %{count}", :blank=>"can't be blank", :too_short=>"is too short (minimum is %{count} characters)", :exclusion=>"is res
erved", :inclusion=>"is not included in the list", :less_than_or_equal_to=>"must be less than or equal to %{count}", :not_a_number=>"is not a number",
 :too_long=>"is too long (maximum is %{count} characters)", :invalid=>"is invalid", :odd=>"must be odd", :greater_than=>"must be greater than %{count}
"}}, :activerecord=>{:errors=>{:messages=>{:record_invalid=>"Validation failed: %{errors}", :taken=>"has already been taken"}}}, :helpers=>{:submit=>{
:submit=>"Save %{model}", :update=>"Update %{model}", :create=>"Create %{model}"}, :select=>{:prompt=>"Please select"}}}}, @initialized=true>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue, but mine was due to having duplicate keys.

In one file, we defined this:

```
en:
  dashboard: "Dashboard"
```

And another we defined

```
en:
  dashboard:
    title: "Some Title"
```

Locally, `I18n.t("dashboard.title")` worked just fine, but on production it did not. The reason was probably due to a load order difference between Heroku and my development machine.

I fixed it by changing the name of the first `dashboard` key so there was no longer an overlap.

Comment: This was exactly my issue. Find for duplicate entries!

Answer (score 1):

This issue does not appear to be Heroku-specific and would happen on any Windows/UNIX co-mingling with Ruby / i18n.

Comment: Very assertive. Do I assume correctly that this answer is out of personal experience? (Makes the answer that much useful. :)

Comment: Heroku uses a standard build of Ruby so this is almost certainly just a Windows/UNIX difference with the BOM mark. There should be nothing unique to the Heroku environment that would be at play here.

Answer (score 0):

Writing this line will also fix the problem in your application.rb

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

Comment: I think you had a different problem, because my problem was not getting the file but parsing its contents: the BOM was ruining the loading of the file contents.

Comment: Yeah heroku didnt read my locales file so when i put that i worked for me