# Rails 3: i18n locale doesn't change on production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, locale

I have been searching for hours to internationalise my application on the "production environment".

Everything works fine on the development environment.

Here are my codes:

in view

```
        <li><%= link_to "العربية", :locale=>'ar' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "English", :locale=>'en' %></li>
```

in application_controller.rb

```
  def set_locale
I18n.locale = params[:locale]
I18n.default_locale = params[:locale] end
```

I am using rails v3.2.1, gem v1.8.17.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong for you here? Is there anything in your specific production environment file that's significantly different to the development one?

Comment: Could you tell us what happens when you click on either link?

Comment: @JoePym , they are the same. I just push the code to heroku.

Comment: @amencarini, it says that the translation is missing ( <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: ar.header.login">Login</span> )

Comment: Here is the answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868309/heroku-not-loading-language-file

Answer (score 0):

in view  haml:

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
  = link_to I18n.name_for_locale(locale), url_for( :locale => locale )
  &nbsp;
```

in application_controller.rb

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```