# Rails I18n not working properly on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-i18n

I18n works as expected locally but not on heroku.  It always shows english even if the browser is set to pt-BR.  We set the locale in a before filter:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_locale

    private

  def set_locale
    I18n.set_preferred_locale(env.http_accept_language)
  end
end

module I18n
  class << self
    def set_preferred_locale(http_accept_language)
      locale = http_accept_language.preferred_language_from(I18n.available_locales)

      if locale.present?
        I18n.locale = locale
        I18n.default_locale = locale  #added based on some stackflow answer about heroku and I18n
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have confirmed through the logger that I18n.locale has the correct value (pt-BR) in views but translations are still coming in english.

I have also tried as a test just setting directly to 'pt-BR' and still get the same result:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter :set_locale

   private

   def set_locale
      I18n.locale = 'pt-BR'
   end
end
```

Comment: I use i18n with success on Heroku, but I don't set the locale based on user browser settings, like I get the feeling you may want to.  Can you edit your question to share the code you use to set the locale?

Comment: Have you set `I18n.available_locales = [:en, :"pt-BR"]` in an initializer or anywhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was setting it up fine.  The issue was that there was a byte order mark in my pt-BR.yml.  Apparently heroku can't load language files with them - [heroku not loading language file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868309/heroku-not-loading-language-file).

I used vim to remove the marker with:

```
:set nobomb
:w
```

Comment: Nice one.  If appropriate, would you be able to edit your question or answer with the output of the error or `heroku logs` so that they can be attributed to issues with BOM?

Comment: Afraid there was no error message.  That is what made this so difficult to take down.  I figured out the file wasn't being loaded by trial and error.

Comment: Trial and error is a tough slog :-)  If all's good now, could you please mark this as the accepted answer for everyone's benefit.

Comment: Tried earlier.  Looks like I need to wait until tomorrow before it will let me.

Comment: Anybody know how to resolve this issue with django and compiled gettext .mo files? I tried the vim :set nobomb, but it doesn't help. No entries in the heroku logs, and my spanish translations work fine. Definitely something with the encoding of the file and heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, i have opened any file and save it with nobomb