# How to solve byte order mark, BOM, in localization files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml, sublimetext3, byte-order-mark

My Rails app's localization works fine locally, but when deployed to Heroku some word don't get translated and renders the "missing translation" span tag.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868309/heroku-not-loading-language-file) seems to have the same problem and have solved it by [removing the offending BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8017885/3205492). But what does this imply, how do I identify and remove offending BOM in my yaml-file?

Or/and what should I look for to check if BOM exists in the file?

I'm editing in Sublime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If BOM is your problem, in Sublime you can go to  **File --> Save With Encoding --> UTF8**.

UTF8 options is implied to be without BOM. You have other option as well UTF8 with BOM.